# Почему не работает условие :not в Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующий код

```
<div class="one">
    <p>Text</p>
    <div class="two">
         <p>Text2</p>
    </div>
</div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".one:not(.two) p").css({"color":"red"});
});
```

Хочу чтобы срабатывало везде, кроме класса two. Сейчас срабатывает везде. Как это лучше сделать?
https://jsfiddle.net/494sp5gx/2/

Ниже предложили решение, но оно не походит к этому случаю https://jsfiddle.net/494sp5gx/3/

```
<div class="one">
    <div>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
         <p>Text2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Какие еще есть варианты?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".one:not(.two) > p").css({"color":"red"});
```

Указывайте на прямого потомка с помощью `>`.

Comment: А где можно почитать про > в Jquery ? Не пойму как оно работает.

Comment: @dimaua  селекторы.... http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B

Comment: Данное решение не подходит, так как не срабатывает в потомках нижнего уровня.

Comment: `"p:not(.two > p)"` для второго случая такое например